# What are the exact semantics of RandomGen's split function supposed to be?

Tags: haskell, random

It seems that in Haskell, the behavior of `split` can be strongly dependent on the chosen (pseudo)random number generator (*PRNG*).
I was drawn to `split` by looking at various ways within the API to generate random numbers.

Say we take the comparatively recent [Threefish](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tf-random-0.5/docs/System-Random-TF.html) generator.

We will need:

```
 λ> import System.Random
 λ> import System.Random.TF
 λ> import Control.Monad.Random
```

Next, we generate sequences of 20 two-digits numbers in 3 different ways:

```
 λ> tg0 = mkTFGen 42
 λ> 
 λ> evalRand  (sequence (replicate 20 $ getRandomR (10,99)))  tg0
[62,99,78,18,38,21,54,25,54,94,62,57,55,69,98,78,99,73,59,24]
 λ> 
 λ> take 20 $ evalRand  (sequence (repeat $ getRandomR (10,99)))  tg0
[62,99,78,18,38,21,54,25,54,94,62,57,55,69,98,78,99,73,59,24]
 λ> 
 λ> take 20 $  evalRand  (getRandomRs (10,99))  tg0
[62,99,78,18,38,21,54,25,54,94,62,57,55,69,98,78,99,73,59,24]
 λ>
```

We get 3 times the same sequence, regardless of whether we're take'ing a prefix of an unlimited sequence or not.

But this is not so for the “standard” StdGen generator. Here:

```
 λ> 
 λ> sg0 = mkStdGen 42
 λ> 
 λ> evalRand  (sequence (replicate 20 $ getRandomR (10,99)))  sg0
[69,79,35,32,84,89,76,39,16,73,73,37,34,96,12,23,45,59,31,34]
 λ> 
 λ> take 20 $ evalRand  (sequence (repeat $ getRandomR (10,99)))  sg0
[69,79,35,32,84,89,76,39,16,73,73,37,34,96,12,23,45,59,31,34]
 λ> 
 λ> take 20 $  evalRand  (getRandomRs (10,99))  sg0
[33,66,18,33,73,38,73,35,59,82,42,44,48,20,58,21,89,14,43,14]
 λ>
```

So here, the third sequence differs from the other ones. It turns out that this is because getRandomRs calls `split` on the current generator.

This can be checked directly in this way:

```
 λ> 
 λ> (sg0a, sg0b) = split sg0
 λ> (tg0a, tg0b) = split tg0
 λ> 
 λ> :{
|λ> let { getRandomDouble :: RandomGen g => g -> Double ;
|λ>       getRandomDouble g = fst $ random g }
|λ> :}
 λ> 
 λ>  λ> 
 λ> getRandomDouble tg0
0.6499718678721916
 λ> getRandomDouble tg0a
0.6499718678721916
 λ> 
 λ> getRandomDouble tg0b
0.7724686371301966
 λ> 
 λ> getRandomDouble sg0
1.0663729393723398e-2
 λ> getRandomDouble sg0a
0.36531519389010025
 λ> 
 λ> getRandomDouble sg0b
0.7740913257381021
 λ>
```

So, in the case of the Threefish generator, the left component of the split (used by `getRandomRs`) generates the same sequence as the original. For the StdGen generator, it generates a different sequence, leading to the surprising result noted in the beginning.

The source code for the `stdSplit` function is [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.0.3/docs/src/System-Random.html). It includes a comment:

```
    -- no statistical foundation for this!
```

**Question**: is the behavior of `stdSplit` legal (in conformity with the language standard) and/or statistically legitimate? I understand there might be a necessity not to break existing client code, but are there guidelines about this to be applied to newer PRNGs?

**Note:** It is rather unusual for a PRNG API to provide a `split` function. It is more common to provide an `advance` function, like here in [Python/NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/random/bit_generators/generated/numpy.random.PCG64.advance.html) for example, and extra generators can be created as required using that `advance` function. For some PRNGs, the `advance` function has a cost of only O(log(numSteps)).

Comment: Well... yes, it conforms to the language standard, in as much as the language standard doesn't say diddlysquat one way or the other about randomness! This is just a tacked-on library that folks find handy, not something that requires deep compiler support or anything like that.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Your comment seems to be an answer.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner: regarding the language standard, I suspected something like this (though my English vocabulary did not yet include “diddly squat”). It's nice to have it confirmed by a proper authority. Thanks !

Comment: Update: in fact there are specific comments about the implementation of `stdSplit` for the Haskell `stdGen` generator in the [OOPSLA2014 SplitMix paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273188325_Fast_Splittable_Pseudorandom_Number_Generators), on page 470.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, H. G. Schaathun in 2015 evaluated the statistical quality of StdGen, tf-random, and other splittable pseudorandom generators in "Evaluation of Splittable Pseudo-Random Generators", and found most of those generators statistically flawed, with the exception of tf-random. (SplitMix was "published after the original submission of [that] paper" and so was not studied there; however, [recent testing](https://github.com/tweag/random-quality/tree/master/results) shows that it appears to do well statistically.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing us to the [H. G. Schaathun paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b82b/c39da0ed8bbe79fa769a2f952ca916fd5900.pdf?_ga=2.887345.1686868413.1588075662-1763949214.1586022019). I was familiar with the substreams approach by [Pierre L'Ecuyer](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/streams00.pdf) but definitely not to the concept of Monte-Carlo trees. I understand a bit better where the Haskell API came from.