# Why does the generator returned by `fst (Random.split gen)` sometimes produce the same results as `gen`?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create random permutations of a list. I'm new to randomness in functional languages and don't have a full grasp on monads yet, but I have used Random.newStdGen and Random.Shuffle.shuffle' in a way that I believe should be working.

The problem I'm running into, is I'm getting a lot of duplicate permutations to the point where it seems that I'm incorrectly using or incorrectly understanding the split function for generators.

The relevant functions are here:

```hs
doGenerateInput :: [[Int]] -> System.Random.StdGen -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
doGenerateInput acc gen n 0 = acc
doGenerateInput acc gen n k =
  doGenerateInput
    (System.Random.Shuffle.shuffle' [1 .. n] n gen : acc) accumulator
    (fst (System.Random.split gen))
    n
    (k -1)

generateInput :: Int -> Int -> IO [[Int]]
generateInput n k = do
  gen <- System.Random.newStdGen
  return (doGenerateInput [] gen n k)
```

Here `generateInput` should create `k` random permutation of `[1..n]`. It splits the generator before passing it to the next level of recursion, so each of the permutations should be statistically unrelated to each other. However the actual results I'm getting include a ton of duplicates. Usually returning the same permutation twice in a row. Sometimes even three times in a row. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Here is an output I received from it.

```
8 18 1 6 17 19 7 9 15 2 11 12 20 16 10 5 4 14 13 3
12 11 8 20 1 6 19 7 9 17 2 13 14 18 10 5 4 16 15 3
3 13 12 9 1 2 8 10 11 19 4 15 16 20 14 7 6 18 17 5
3 13 12 9 1 2 8 10 11 19 4 15 16 20 14 7 6 18 17 5
7 8 3 15 14 16 20 11 1 2 10 12 13 5 4 19 6 18 17 9
7 8 3 15 14 16 20 11 1 2 10 12 13 5 4 19 6 18 17 9
7 8 3 15 14 16 20 11 1 2 10 12 13 5 4 19 6 18 17 9
7 8 3 15 14 16 20 11 1 2 10 12 13 5 4 19 6 18 17 9
8 6 9 10 7 11 3 19 18 20 15 1 2 14 17 16 4 12 5 13
18 8 6 9 10 7 11 3 20 19 15 1 2 14 17 16 4 12 5 13
8 11 5 13 15 4 20 18 16 14 10 3 12 1 19 7 9 6 2 17
16 8 11 5 13 6 15 18 4 19 17 12 3 14 1 9 10 7 2 20
2 17 9 12 6 14 7 16 19 5 20 18 13 4 15 1 8 11 3 10
7 2 18 10 6 14 8 16 9 19 5 20 15 4 17 1 11 13 3 12
17 7 2 19 13 10 6 15 8 18 9 5 14 11 16 3 1 20 4 12
11 4 19 8 2 6 16 13 9 18 10 12 20 3 7 15 5 1 17 14
17 11 4 20 13 10 8 2 6 19 15 9 3 14 5 18 16 7 1 12
17 11 4 20 13 10 8 2 6 19 15 9 3 14 5 18 16 7 1 12
12 18 11 4 1 15 13 9 3 7 17 10 5 16 6 20 19 8 2 14
12 18 11 4 1 15 13 9 3 7 17 10 5 16 6 20 19 8 2 14
```

Based on the documentation for `split`, I would expect that the two generators returned from split are not correlated. But the rate of duplicates seems to indicate that generating a random number with `fst (split gen)` produces the same result as `gen` about half the time.

> Returns two distinct pseudo-random number generators. Implementations should take care to ensure that the resulting generators are not correlated.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.2.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:split

**I have found a solution, but I don't understand why it works**

If I use `snd (split gen)` instead of `fst (split gen)`, I do not get any repeats. However based on the documentation, I'm unsure of why. It doesn't make any notes of a difference between the first and second generators returned.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: "Implementations should take care to ensure that the *resulting generators* are not correlated."  It sounds like the two resulting generators are not correlated with *each other*. I'm not sure if there's a requirement that they are also not correlated with the original generator (the argument given to `split`)

Comment: I don't think you need `split` at all. Random number libraries in imperative languages (C++, Python) do **not** provide anything like split. You can use `shuffleM` together with `replicateM`.

Comment: Roughly put, if `(a,b) = split g`, then `a` can be assumed to be independent from `b`, but neither `a` nor `b` can be assumed to be independent from `g` -- indeed, `(a,b)` can be _deterministically_ computed from `g` (indeed, as `split g`).

Comment: It is not clear for me whether you are using version 1.1 or 1.2 of the System.Random module. Your problem with `split` might be related to [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416756/what-are-the-exact-semantics-of-randomgens-split-function-supposed-to-be) of mine. In any case, you do not need `split` for a simple *sequential and finite* random object generation problem.

Comment: Bleh. That `shuffle'` has a bad type -- it should be `RandomGen gen => [a] -> Int -> gen -> ([a], gen)` or similar, returning the updated random generator state after it has done all the shuffling. Then `split` is not needed; you simply pass the output of the better shuffle to the recursive call to `doGenerateInput`. Bonus points if you also modify `doGenerateInput`'s type similarly, returning the updated generator after all the permutations are generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's something of an assumption in the design of `random` that a `RandomGen` value is only used once. When you reuse them, weird things can happen. I don't know how `RandomGen`'s `split` is implemented to give you this outcome, but I can tell you it's assuming you're not going to do what you're doing. Passing `gen` to both `split` and `shuffle'` is using it twice. The intended way to use `split` for your use case would be to call split up front, and then pass one of its return values to `shuffle'` and the other to the recursive call.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use `split`, which is only required typically in arborescent structures.

You could generate the permutations like this:

```
$ ghci
 GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 ...
 λ> 
 λ> import System.Random
 λ> import Control.Monad
 λ> import Control.Monad.Random
 λ> import System.Random.Shuffle
 λ> 
 λ> :type replicateM
 replicateM :: Applicative m => Int -> m a -> m [a]
 λ> 
 λ> :type shuffleM
 shuffleM :: MonadRandom m => [a] -> m [a]
 λ> 
 λ> action n k = replicateM k (shuffleM [1..n])
 λ> 
 λ> :type  action 10 6
 action 10 6 :: (MonadRandom m, Num a, Enum a) => m [[a]]
 λ> 
 λ> randomSeed = 42
 λ> gen0 = mkStdGen randomSeed
 λ> 
 λ> (xss,gen1) = runRand (action 10 6) gen0
 λ> 
 λ> printAsLines zs = mapM_  (putStrLn . show)  zs
 λ> 
 λ> printAsLines xss
 [10,7,4,6,3,9,1,8,2,5]
 [4,1,3,2,7,8,10,9,6,5]
 [2,8,6,9,1,5,7,4,3,10]
 [7,10,5,2,9,1,6,4,8,3]
 [3,7,4,10,8,1,2,5,6,9]
 [9,1,2,4,3,8,7,6,5,10]
 λ>
```